# How to freeze the legend while scrolling

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with lots of colors and a legend at the right side. But its at the top and when I scroll down the legend goes up and becomes non-visible.

[Example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78p3X.png)

I need to keep the marked lines present while scrolling down.

Is there a way I can make certain cells freeze while I scroll down ?

Note: I tried the New Window -> View Side by Side. Its not what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the ribbon, you can use "View" > "Split"

This will give you four quadrants that can be manipulated independently of each other.
*(To remove quadrants or halves, simply double-click the dragg-able separator line.)*

[image]